# struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct error Phoenix 1.3

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a contact form in a phoenix 1.3 app.  I used `mix phx.gen.html` to create the relevant files. However, I'm getting a compilation error when trying to start the server:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/iotc/web/controllers/email_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/iotc/web/controllers/email_controller.ex:7: Email.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct Email
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    lib/iotc/web/controllers/email_controller.ex:6: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Looking at some other posts with a similar issue, it could be related to the alias, but I have `alias Itoc.Contact` in the controller, and I don't think `alias Iotc.Contact.Email` would be right here.

**email_controller.ex**

```
defmodule Iotc.Web.EmailController do
  use Iotc.Web, :controller
  alias Iotc.Contact

  def index(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Email.changeset(%Email{})
    emails = Contact.list_emails()
    render(conn, "index.html", emails: emails, changeset: changeset)
  end

...
```

**email.ex**

```
defmodule Iotc.Contact.Email do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Iotc.Contact.Email


  schema "contact_emails" do
    field :email, :string
    field :event, :string
    field :message, :string
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(%Email{} = email, attrs) do
    email
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email, :message, :event])
    |> validate_required([:name, :email, :message, :event])
  end
end
```

Comment: You do need that alias if you want to use the name `Email`. You can also switch to `Contact.Email` if you want to only alias the `Contact` module.

Comment: OK makes sense. I've updated it to the controller to :

`changeset = Contact.Email.changeset(%Contact.Email{})`

But I now get:

`warning: function Iotc.Contact.Email.changeset/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * changeset/2`

Answer (score 0):

With respect to this

> OK makes sense. I've updated it to the controller to : changeset =
>   Contact.Email.changeset(%Contact.Email{}) But I now get: warning:
>   function Iotc.Contact.Email.changeset/1 is undefined or private. Did
>   you mean one of: * changeset/2

You only have one function `changeset/2` defined in the Email module.

But you're doing `Contact.Email.changeset(%Contact.Email{})` passing only one argument. Do ``Contact.Email.changeset(%Contact.Email{})` and it should work.

The `/2` part of the signature tells you the **arity** of the function, namely how many arguments takes.